# C# split string that have random white space into string array

Tags: c#, regex, linq

Currently i having a string as below that i had to split them into array, which method is the best to filter it and put into array?

```
                 1     29.670      2.000   1546.547      0.507      1.483
```

The final result i would like to get in array will be
1
29.670
2.000
1546.547
1.483

Is that REGEX a best solution on it or LinQ is better?

Comment: `.Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
using System.Linq;

var str = "                 1     29.670      2.000   1546.547      0.507      1.483";
var strArr = str.Split(' ').Where(x => x != string.Empty).ToArray();
```

It is not optimal, but can help you filter your result as you wish in future, but the fastest way is using options in Split() method as in one of the coments to your post `.Split(' ', System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var input = "                 1     29.670      2.000   1546.547      0.507      1.483";
        
var arr = Regex.Replace(input, @"\s+", "#")
    .Split('#')
    .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x))
    .Select(x => float.Parse(x))
    .Where(x => x >= 1);
```